# Servletcontainer.init() not invoked after upgrade karaf from 4.3.7 to 4..4.3

Tags: java, rest, osgi, apache-karaf, servlet-container

`We were upgrading from karaf 4.3.7 to 4.4.3

we were facing an issue like servletcontainer.init(webconfig) not invoked after upgraded to 4.4.3 .

our class is below,

```
`import static org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_INIT_PARAM_PREFIX;
import static org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_NAME;
import static org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.HttpWhiteboardConstants.HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN;
@Component (xmlns = "http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.2.0",
        immediate = true,
        service = { Servlet.class, ProbeRestartService.class },
        property = {
                     HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN + "=/app/*",
                     HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_NAME + "=ApplicationConfiguration API",
                     HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_INIT_PARAM_PREFIX + ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS
                             + "=com.project.example.AppConfApplication"
        })
public class ApplicationConfigurationServlet extends ServletContainer implements ProbeRestartService, ProbeService
{

private boolean isServletinitialised = false;
@Override
    protected void init(WebConfig webConfig) throws ServletException
    {
        LOG.error("NN AppServletconfig init");
        isServletinitialised  = true;
        ------
    }`
```

isServletinitialised  is set to true within init() but init method not invoked hence isServletinitialised  is false and After karaf startup, we have a healthchecker which checks this boolean isServletinitialised for false on every 5 mins. if isServletinitialised  is false for 5 tries in healthcheck then it restarts the pod in kubernetes.

My question is why servletcontainer.init not getting invoked after karaf 4.4.3 upgrade.

Pls help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Karaf 4.4.x uses Pax Web 8 which includes complete refactoring of Whiteboard implementation (and entire structure).

One of the changes is related to specification compliance and servlets are *not* initialized when registered - only lazily initialized on first request.

In servlet specification you can use `<load-on-startup>` in your `web.xml`, but OSGi CMPN Whiteboard specification doesn't mention this.

In Pax Web you can use `load-on-startup` service registration property though. So use:

```
property = {
    HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_PATTERN + "=/app/*",
    HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_NAME + "=ApplicationConfiguration API",
    HTTP_WHITEBOARD_SERVLET_INIT_PARAM_PREFIX + ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS
        + "=com.project.example.AppConfApplication",
    "load-on-startup=1"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. it works for me. But now during servletcontainer.init() method call, getting below exception now,   Pls help on this.                                               
               java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ParamCreationFactory found for Parameter source org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter

Comment: Is there any official osgi link mentioning this "One of the changes is related to specification compliance and servlets are not initialized when registered - only lazily initialized on first request." pls share. so that we need to update our health check accordingly.

Comment: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#Assembling_the_descriptor - it says "Servlets are initialized either lazily at request processing time or eagerly during deployment. In the latter case, they are initialized in the order indicated by their load-on-startup elements". OSGi CMPN Whiteboard spec says about "initialization before start of request serving": https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/8.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#service.http.whiteboard-i21223311

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing information with links.  We have updated our health check based on this.