# Getting exception while doing super.init(webconfig) from init(webconfig) within class extends servletcontainer in karaf 4.4.3

Tags: java, rest, apache-karaf, servlet-container

we were upgrading to karaf 4.4.3. During karaf bundles startup, Getting exception while doing super.init(webconfig) from init(webconfig) within class extends servletcontainer in karaf 4.4.3. please help.

````
```
228 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ParamCreationFactory found for Parameter source org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter.
            229         at org.glassfish.jersey.model.Parameter.createParameter(Parameter.java:339)
            230         at org.glassfish.jersey.model.Parameter.create(Parameter.java:294)
            231         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter.create(Parameter.java:68)
            232         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.checkResourceClassFields(IntrospectionModeller.java:205)
            233         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.doCreateResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:117)
            234         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.access$000(IntrospectionModeller.java:58)
            235         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:90)
            236         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller$1.call(IntrospectionModeller.java:87)
            237         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
            238         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
            239         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
            240         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.IntrospectionModeller.createResourceBuilder(IntrospectionModeller.java:87)
            241         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource.from(Resource.java:781)
            242         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceBagConfigurator.init(ResourceBagConfigurator.java:55)
            243         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:335)
            244         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.lambda$initialize$1(ApplicationHandler.java:297)
            245         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
            246         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
            247         at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:232)
            248         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:296)
            249         at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:261)
            250         at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
            251         at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:154)
            252         at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:339)
            253         at com.example.ApplicationConfigurationServlet.init(ApplicationConfigurationServlet.java:85)
```
````

Comment: Without seeing entire application (dependencies) I can't say anything - now this is not related to OSGi, Pax Web or Karaf, there's something missing which is required by Jersey.

Comment: Same thing as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76415623/servletcontainer-init-not-invoked-after-upgrade-karaf-from-4-3-7-to-4-4-3. but now when init method call happens, we do super.init(webconfig) within that, there it throws this in karaf 4.4.3 with pax web jetty.  but same does not cause issues with karaf 4.3.7. why this issue happen in karaf 4.4.3 with pax web jetty?  Any jetty related dependent classes missing in pax web jetty in 4.4.3 karaf? pls help on this to confirm.

Comment: Without seeing your maven project I can't help much... sorry.

Comment: it looks like org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter class missing in glassfish in karaf 4.4.3? is it?

Comment: Karaf doesn't "contain" Glassfish. It allows you to install relevant bundle but it's up to you.